# upload images and video in server

Tags: php, mysql

I want to upload video and images in database on server. I used following code, but when I use this code in my `localhost` then it works but when I upload through the server, it shows errors.

Here is my code:

```
$target = "upload/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
$ok=1; 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{
echo "The file ".basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']). " has been uploaded";
} 
else {
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
```

And here are the error messages:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(upload/logo.JPG) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed
>    to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\hiznherzbridalshow.com\httpdocs
>       \hiznherz_new\test2.php on line 31
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move
>        'C:\Windows\Temp\php7648.tmp' to 'upload/logo.JPG' in C:\Inetpub\vhosts
>        \hiznherzbridalshow.com\httpdocs\hiznherz_new\test2.php on line 31

Comment: Normally it would be check the permissions of the directory you are attempting to upload to, but it appears as tho you may be on a windows server. But if it is in fact a linux box, you want to make sure the permissions for the folder you are attempting to upload to are at least 0755 or 0777.

Comment: i m fresher and i dnt know abt it how can i do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP provides a function, [chmod()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) for the task. Change your folder permissions manually or dynamically.

Change your folder permission into `775` or `777`

**Updated**

add this code into your php

```
chmod("upload", 0777);
```

Comment: from where i changed the permission

Comment: Goto your c panel and select your folder and change folder permission

Comment: See my updated answer. put this code and change your folder permission

Comment: Thanking you so much guys